# Is it correct to expect internal updates of a SwiftUI DynamicProperty property wrapper to trigger a view update?

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

I'm attempting to create a custom property wrapper supported by SwiftUI, meaning that changes to the corresponding properties values would cause an update to the SwiftUI view. Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
@propertyWrapper
public struct Foo: DynamicProperty {
    @ObservedObject var observed: SomeObservedObject

    public var wrappedValue: [SomeValue] {
        return observed.value
    }
}
```

I see that even if my `ObservedObject` is contained inside of my custom property wrapper, SwiftUI still catches the changes to `SomeObservedObject` as long as:

- My property wrapper is a struct
- My property wrapper conforms to `DynamicProperty`

Unfortunately the docs are sparse and I have a hard time telling if this only works out of luck with the current SwiftUI implementation.

The docs of `DynamicProperty` (within Xcode, not online) seem to indicate that such a property is a property that is changed from the outside causing the view to redraw, but there is no guarantee about what happens when you conform your own types to this protocol.

Can I expect this to continue working in future SwiftUI releases?

Comment: It is not clear what's the expectation of this topic... answer on the one last question? Will you really believe if someone answer "yes, sure, you can expect"? ))

Answer (score 17):

Ok... here is alternate approach to get similar thing... but as struct only `DynamicProperty` wrapped around `@State` (to force view refresh).

It is simple wrapper but gives possibility to incapsulate any custom calculations with following view refresh... and as said using value-only types.

Here is demo (tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2):

[image: DynamicProperty as wrapper on @State]

Here is code:

```
import SwiftUI

@propertyWrapper
struct Refreshing<Value> : DynamicProperty {
    let storage: State<Value>

    init(wrappedValue value: Value) {
        self.storage = State<Value>(initialValue: value)
    }
    
    public var wrappedValue: Value {
        get { storage.wrappedValue }
        
        nonmutating set { self.process(newValue) }
    }
    
    public var projectedValue: Binding<Value> {
        storage.projectedValue
    }
    
    private func process(_ value: Value) {
        // do some something here or in background queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.storage.wrappedValue = value
        }
    }
    
}


struct TestPropertyWrapper: View {
    
    @Refreshing var counter: Int = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Value: \(counter)")
            Divider()
            Button("Increase") {
                self.counter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the question in your title, no. For example, here is some code that doesn't work:

```
class Storage {
    var value = 0
}

@propertyWrapper
struct MyState: DynamicProperty {
    var storage = Storage()

    var wrappedValue: Int {
        get { storage.value }

        nonmutating set {
            storage.value = newValue // This doesn't work
        }
    }
}
```

So apparently you still need to put a `State` or `ObservedObject` etc. inside your `DynamicProperty` to trigger an update as Asperi did, a `DynamicProperty` itself doesn't enforce any update.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and use a Combine publisher with your `@propertyWrapper` the same way a `@Published` object from SwiftUI would do.

By passing the publisher of your `@porpertyWrapper` to a `projectedValue`, you will have a custom Combine publisher that you can use within your SwiftUI view and call the `$` to keep track of the value changes over time.

The use in your SwiftUI view or inside a view model:

```
@Foo(defaultValue: "foo") var value: String

// For your view model or SwiftUI View
$value
```

Your full custom Combine publisher as a `@propertyWrapper`:

```
import Combine

@propertyWrapper
struct Foo<Value> {

  var defaultValue: Value

  // Combine publisher to project value over time. 
  private let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Value, Never>()

  var wrappedValue: Value {
    get {
      return defaultValue
    }
    set {
      defaultValue = newValue
      publisher.send(newValue)
    }
  }

  // Project the updated value using the Combine publisher.
  var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
    publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct, here is an example:

```
class SomeObservedObject : ObservableObject {
    @Published var counter = 0
}

@propertyWrapper struct Foo: DynamicProperty {

    @StateObject var object = SomeObservedObject()

    public var wrappedValue: Int {
        get {
            object.counter
        }
        nonmutating set {
            object.counter = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

When a View using `@Foo` is recreated, SwiftUI passes the Foo struct the same object as last time, so has the same counter value. When setting the foo var, this is set on the `ObservableObject`'s `@Published` which SwiftUI detects as a change and causes the body to be recomputed.

Try it out!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var counter = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(counter) Hello, world!")
            Button("Increment") {
                counter = counter + 1
            }
            ContentView2()
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView2: View {
    @Foo var foo
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(foo) Hello, world!")
            Button("Increment") {
                foo = foo + 1
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

When the second button is tapped the counter stored in `Foo` is updated. When first button is tapped, `ContentView`'s body is called and `ContentView2()` is recreated but keeps the same counter as last time. Now `SomeObservedObject` can be a `NSObject` and implement a `delegate` protocol for example.