# How to Make Custom Property Wrapper Bindable, Possibly with @State?

Tags: swift, properties, swiftui, state, property-wrapper

I have created a custom property wrapper that writes and reads from a file as its setter and getter.

```swift
@propertyWrapper struct Specifier<Value> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: Value
    let plistPath: String
    
    var prefs: NSDictionary {
        NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath) ?? NSDictionary()
    }

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            return prefs.value(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            prefs.setValue(newValue, forKey: key)
            prefs.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to use this as in a settings view like so:

```swift
struct PrefsView: View {
    @Specifier<Bool>(key: "enable", defaultValue: true, plistPath: "/Library/path/to/Prefs.plist") private var enable

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("Enable", isOn: $enable)
        }
    }

}
```

I am given the following error:

```
Cannot find '$enable' in scope
```

How might I achieve this effect of writing and reading to a file for setting and getting variable but also allow it to bind to a value?

NOTE: My project does not need to be "App Store Legal"

Comment: You might find helpful the following https://stackoverflow.com/a/59622915/12299030.

Answer (score 6):

Your property wrapper returns `Bool` and not `Binding<Bool>` which is needed by the `Toggle`.

You can specify the `projectedValue` (as NewDev suggested) - this will allow you to access the `Binding` with the `$`:

```
@propertyWrapper struct Specifier<Value> {
    ...

    var wrappedValue: Value {
        get {
            projectedValue.wrappedValue
        }
        set {
            projectedValue.wrappedValue = newValue
        }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: Binding<Value> {
        .init(get: {
            prefs.value(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue
        }, set: {
            prefs.setValue($0, forKey: key)
            prefs.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Specifier(key: "enable", defaultValue: true, plistPath: "/Library/path/to/Prefs.plist") private var enable

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("Enable", isOn: $enable)
            Text(String(enable))
        }
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you can change the return type of the `wrappedValue` to `Binding<Bool>`:

```
@propertyWrapper struct Specifier<Value> {
    ...

    var wrappedValue: Binding<Value> {
        .init(get: {
            prefs.value(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue
        }, set: {
            prefs.setValue($0, forKey: key)
            prefs.write(toFile: plistPath, atomically: true)
        })
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Specifier(key: "enable", defaultValue: true, plistPath: "/Library/path/to/Prefs.plist") private var enable

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Toggle("Enable", isOn: enable) // access as a Binding
            Text(String(enable.wrappedValue)) // access as a Bool
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the awesome, quick response! Just one side problem: the compiler now expects the defaultValue parameter to be of type `Binding<Value>` as your solution currently yields a `cannot convert value of type 'Bool' to expected argument type 'Binding<Bool>'` error ... do you have any pointers on how I might resolve this?

Comment: @YulkyTulky Please check how I use the `Specifier` in the `ContentView` - the `Value` is inferred, you don't need to call `@Specifier<Bool>`.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right! I was trying to not just blindly copy-paste code and didn't notice that change ... thank you!

Comment: You could also return a wrappedValue as a `Bool` (as you normally would), and return a projected value as a `Binding`

Comment: @NewDev Thanks, it looks better now as there's no need to use `enable.wrappedValue` when accessing the Bool value.