# @propertywrapper in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, property-wrapper

I created a @propertyWrapper to limit the number a variable can reach. I tried it in a SwiftUI view with a button that increases the value of the variable and it works, the variable stops at the maximum number set in the initializer. However if I try it with a Textflied it doesn't work, if I insert a higher number than the one set nothing happens, it makes me do it. How can I solve this problem, I know the problem has to do with Binding but I don't know exactly what it is, here is the code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @Maximum(maximum: 12) var quantity: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                TextField("", value: $quantity, format: .number, prompt: Text("Pizza").foregroundColor(.red))
                
                Button {
                    quantity += 1
                } label: {
                    Text("\(quantity)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Maximum<T: Comparable> where T: Numeric {
    @State private var number: T = 0

    var max: T

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { number }
        nonmutating set { number = min(newValue, max) }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: Binding<T> {
        Binding(
            get: { wrappedValue },
            set: { wrappedValue = $0 }
        )
    }
    
    init(maximum: T){
        max = maximum
    }
}

extension Maximum: DynamicProperty {
    
}
```

Comment: Adding just extension of DynamicProperty does not make it source of updates for view. Wrap it around state, next should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59622915/12299030.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Asperi is exactly right as to how to create the property wrapper. However, that does not solve the problem of the `TextField()`. The issue seems to be that You are not actually using `$quantity` on your `TextField`, but rather are using a string from the formatter that is derived from `$quantity.` That just doesn't seem to allow the update mechanism to work properly.

However, you can fix this simply by feeding a `@State` string into the `TextField`, and then updating everything in an `.onChange(of:)`. This allows you to set `quantity` to the `Int` value of the `TextField`, and the maximum prevents the `quantity` from going too high. You then turn around and set your string to the `quantity.description` to keep everything in sync.

One last thing, I changed the `keyboardType` to `.decimalPad` to make inputting easier.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @Maximum(maximum: 12) var quantity: Int
    @State private var qtyString = "0"
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Form{
                TextField("", text: $qtyString, prompt: Text("Pizza").foregroundColor(.red))
                    .onChange(of: qtyString) { newValue in
                        if let newInt = Int(newValue) {
                            quantity = newInt
                            qtyString = quantity.description
                        }
                    }
                    .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                Button {
                    quantity += 1
                } label: {
                    Text("\(quantity)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@propertyWrapper
struct Maximum<T: Comparable>: DynamicProperty where T: Numeric {
    let number: State<T> = State(initialValue: 0)
    
    var max: T
    
    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { number.wrappedValue }
        nonmutating set { number.wrappedValue = min(newValue, max) }
    }
    
    var projectedValue: Binding<T> {
        Binding(
            get: { wrappedValue },
            set: { wrappedValue = $0 }
        )
    }
    
    init(maximum: T){
        max = maximum
    }
}
```